# Why is .map function returning undefined objects in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to fetch JSON data from my API to import to Google Sheets using Google Apps Script. Everything is working as expected, except for when I'm trying to map the object, the result array returns undefined objects.

Here's my script:

​

```js
function GETMYJSONDATA() {

  var options = {
    "method" : "get",
    "headers" : {
    "Authorization": "Bearer REDACTED"
  }
};

const url = "REDACTED"
const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
const dataAsText = res.getContentText()
const data = JSON.parse(dataAsText)

const results = data.response.users.map (user => {
  return
    [user["department_text"]]
})
  return results
}
```

​Below is the JSON response from my API (raw) and the Apps Script debugger result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to try to return the property as an array? `[user["department_text"]]` or did you mean `user["department_text"]` to just return the property value?

Comment: Please confirm there is a warning message on the console that the posted code contains unreachable code after the return statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the value you need to return is on a new line after the `return`:

```js
return
[user["department_text"]]
```

Once you put them on the same line, it should return proper value.

Answer (score 1):

This

```js
return
[user["department_text"]]
```

Must be a one line:

```
return [user["department_text"]]
```